# Separator line in UITableview for first cell does not appears iOS 7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7

There is an issue which does not shows separator line for first cell of UITableView. This happens only in case of iOS 7. I have placed an UITableView in PopOverController in case of iPad and when this table is displayed the line separator for first cell disappears as shown in screen shot. Any solution?

[image: Line separator for first cell is missing]

Comment: did you got any answer for this i'm getting issue on my iPad

Answer (score 0):

Check if you return the correct height for all of the cells. See if you implemented tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: I have checked these basic stuffs.

Comment: also check the IB. There are are 2 places where you can enter row height - table view and cell object. Maybe you didn't realise you are having a bigger cell.

Comment: Still looking for solution for this.This happen with system cell styles also.